# Why doesn't crm dynamics model have attribute validations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, dynamics-crm-2011

CRM has a model [generation tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844(v=crm.5).aspx), that can be used at development time in order to facilitate the usage of early binding. The data model is defined in this structure:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Note that is attached to one or more objects, including other notes.
    /// </summary>
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
    [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.EntityLogicalNameAttribute("annotation")]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("CrmSvcUtil", "5.0.9690.3339")]
    public partial class Annotation : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Default Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public Annotation() : 
                base(EntityLogicalName)
        {
        }

        public const string EntityLogicalName = "annotation";

        public const int EntityTypeCode = 5;

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanging(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }...
...
```

And the usage is very simple:

```
var note = new Annotation();
note.noteText = "this is my note";
..
```

Fields on the classes above all have some kind of defined bounds. For example, ints cannot be negative, strings need to be under 10 chars, [etc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)

**Is it possible to trick the model generator tool to include attributes on fields?**

The intended result is to have a class that has bounds on every field:

```
    public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Price")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\$?\d+(\.(\d{2}))?$")]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://crmcodegenerator.codeplex.com/. I have no relation to this project and have not used it but I've long been interested in seeing `CrmSvcUtil.exe` replaced with T4 templates (which, to me, are the proper way to do code generation in the .NET/Visual Studio world.

Comment: @Nicknow please make that into an answer

Answer (score 3):

The CrmSvcUtil allows for you to extend the model and you could add your own attributes,  via implementing one of their interfaces, I believe the ICodeGenerationService.  You'll have to understand how to manipulate the CodeDom which is very verbose.